# Where can I find APPLICATION_ID

Tags: android, google-cast, android-cast-api

I'm learning cast api for android and I'm stuck at this part:

```
mMediaRouteSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
  .addControlCategory(CastMediaControlIntent.categoryForCast("YOUR_APPLICATION_ID"))
  .build();
```

Where can I find this `APPLICATION_ID` and what is it?

Comment: Does it require OUTH access?

Comment: they didn't say anything about this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, when doing [Google Cast Android Sender Application tutorial](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender), you should do multiple steps not described well on site to develop Chromecast applications:

1. You must [sign up (yes, pay 5$) for Google Cast SDK](https://cast.google.com/publish/#/signup)
2. After this process, I suggest you to add your device serial number in [Google Cast SDK Developer Console](https://cast.google.com/publish/#/overview) since it's 15 minute long process. More details about this process you can find on [Google Cast Registration page](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/registration)
3. While waiting for device registration, add your application on [Google Cast SDK Developer Console](https://cast.google.com/publish/#/overview) by clicking on [Add new Application](https://cast.google.com/publish/#/applications/new). Choose **Styled Media Receiver** in next step, and you can put anything in **Application Name**
4. By saving application, you'll get `YOUR_APPLICATION_ID`
5. After 15 minutes (or when adding device is ready), don't forget to do step 6. and 7. from [Google Cast Registration page](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/registration)

   - In the Chromecast setup app, select your Chromecast and check the box, Send this Chromecast's serial number when checking for updates.
   - Restart your Cast device: disconnect the power or USB cable from the device, then reconnect it (or you can simply click reboot on Chromecast setup app)

Comment: All the necessary steps are documented if you read the docs: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/developers

Comment: Ali Naddaf, the above descriptions are precisely correct, while the tutorial doc you are pointing to is a timethief even on such a simple matter as using the default app id, which is seemingly not implemented at all: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid application ID: CastMediaControlIntent.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to register your application on the **[dashboard here](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/registration)**.

After registration, you would be given a APPLICATION ID for your application, which you can then use for development.

Excerpt from the **[documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/cast.html)** :

> Before you can develop and test apps on your own Google Cast device,
>   you need to acquire an app ID for your API calls and register your
>   Google Cast device (such as a Chromecast) as a development device. For
>   details, read the Registration guide.

Comment: So your saying that i must pay and buy a chrome device to develop something?

Comment: If you are building a Custom Receiver, then yes. Go through this : https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/registration

Comment: You don't need to register if you can use the Default Receiver (see the cast documentation) but even if you do that, you still need to have a chromecast device to run the app and develop it; without that, it is almost impossible to develop something for chromecast (or another Cast device like an Android TV).