# Android permission not granted

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-permissions

I've created my own android.jar so I can use the hidden API call **'DisplayManager.connectWifiDisplay()'**.

When I run the app and call the method, after connecting to a display via **Wifi** Direct,

I get the following exception:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission required to connect to a wifi display: Neither user 10105 nor current process has android.permission.CONFIGURE_WIFI_DISPLAY.
>   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
>                                                                                                             at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.hardware.display.IDisplayManager$Stub$Proxy.connectWifiDisplay(IDisplayManager.java:344)
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.hardware.display.DisplayManagerGlobal.connectWifiDisplay(DisplayManagerGlobal.java:309)
>                                                                                                             at
>   android.hardware.display.DisplayManager.connectWifiDisplay(DisplayManager.java:404)

However, I have included the **CONFIGURE_WIFI_DISPLAY** and **CONTROL_WIFI_DISPLAY** permissions in my **AndroidManifest**. Any hints on what I could be missing here?

**EDIT**: I'm using Android L.

Comment: are you using a device with Android M?

Comment: What is the android version in your testing device?

Comment: @CalumMcCall I would love to see this code if you are willing to share. Working on a similar project currently.

Comment: @bearsmahoney I unfortunately don't have the code to hand. However, the steps to actually get this working are documented here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34182702/158703

Comment: @CalumMcCall thanks for the tip! Much appreciated.

Comment: @CalumMcCall have you successfully implemented this code? or any suggestion for this custom android.jar

Comment: @GiteekaSawlani yes, I described a method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34182702/158703)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of those permissions have a `signature` protection level (at least on Android 6.0 -- you will need to research if that protection level has changed over the years).

Hence, unless your app is signed by the platform signing key, you cannot hold those permissions, despite having them in your manifest.

Comment: I'm using 5.1. Assuming they do have signature protection level, what are my options? Is it possible to sign the app with the signing key myself? Can I bypass this at all?

Comment: @CalumMcCall: "what are my options?" -- build your own custom ROM, then sign the apps with the same signing key that you used to sign the ROM. Or, strike a deal with a device manufacturer to bundle your apps with their device, signed by their signing key.

Answer (score -3):

I don't know if this is what you want, but you can try using this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```