# Broadcast Receiver for Cast Connectivity in Android

Tags: android, casting, broadcastreceiver, miracast

I don't want to use google cast code to connect devices from my app but needed to just check whether the phone is connected to any cast Device.

Do we get any Receiver/listener for this check?

Thanks!

EDIT:
I have tried to get Cast State as following as mentioned by Chris,

1. Add following in Manifest

> ```
> <meta-data
>             android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.OPTIONS_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME"
>             android:value=".CastOptionsProvider" />
> ```

2. Create CastOptionProvider Class

> ```
> public class CastOptionsProvider implements OptionsProvider {
>     @Override
>     public CastOptions getCastOptions(Context context) {
>         return new CastOptions.Builder()
>                 .build();
>     }
>     @Override
>     public List<SessionProvider> getAdditionalSessionProviders(Context context) {
>         return null;
>     }
> }
> ```

3. Reading state in MainActivity as,

> CastContext mCastContext = CastContext.getSharedInstance(context);
>           if (mCastContext != null) {
>               int x = mCastContext.getCastState();
>
> ```
>     }
> ```

Here Value of x is always "1" i.e. no Devices Available, eventhough the phone is connected to any Miracast Device.

Answer (score 1):

CastContext:

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/CastContext

*getCastState* will tell you whether you're connected or you can call *addCastStateListener* to detect when the state changes.

Comment: Do I have to create class CastOptionsProvider for this? as I will not be having the ReceiverApplicationId to create CastOptions Object